# Is it okay to make really large linear gradients?

Tags: css, linear-gradients, html-rendering

For a link hover effect, I'd like the background color to be the same as the current text color with a bit of transparency. Since you can't add alpha to `currentColor` directly, a trick I came up with is to use a really stretched-out gradient (see below).

This works well, but I'm not sure if having endpoints way off the charts is safe to do, resource-wise. Does the browser have to generate the entire gradient (which would be a huge image) to show only a portion of it, or does it only generate the portion that's necessary? If there are lots of these on one page, does the browser have to re-generate it for every instance?

In short, *would making huge gradients like the one below cause performance issues, or is it okay to do?*

```css
a {
    color: blue;
}
a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(currentColor -25000%, transparent 10000%);
    /* stretched out far enough so you only see a single color */
    /* (these values work like an alpha of 0.25) */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">lorem ipsum</a>
<a href="#" style="color: red;">lorem ipsum</a>
```

Comment: That entirely depends on how the browser implements gradients and how efficient it is at doing so. Benchmark it with a representative example on all the browsers you care about…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You could use a pseudo element and do it like this.

```css
.link {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.link::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: currentColor;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 140ms ease;
}

.link:hover::after {
  opacity: .4;
  transition: opacity 140ms ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="#0" class="link">press</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a less hackish way to do it.
What would you suggest we do with the question now? It doesn't make much sense to ask about something I'm no longer using, and it was a little vague to begin with.

Comment: @vvye Your question was a question and got an answer. I suggest you accept this as the answer :)